# Problems with GRUB install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

A few days ago I did install Ubuntu with 3 partitions, swap / and /home, then I disconnected the hard drive and I installed Windows 7 on another hard drive. The problem is: I don't get the GRUB menu to choose between operating systems.

I tried `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`, but it gives me the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: warning: The file system 'ext2' not allow wardrobe.
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: warning: Can not embed. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are unreliable and their use is not recommended ..
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

What do I do?

Comment: For more about grub you can read the docs here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Answer (score 0):

You need to update grub menu entries.
Open a terminal by pressing<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following:

```
sudo update-grub /dev/sdb
```

replacing sdb above with sda, sdb, sdc, sdd, or whatever drive your GRUB MBR resides on.